# Is "stark still" an appropriate way to describe someone who is standing very still?

Tags: vocabulary

Is "stark still" an appropriate way to describe someone who is standing very still?

e.g. "He stood stark still."

Comment: Ir’s ***stock*** still.

Comment: It's not what you'd call idiomatic.  Could work, in fiction.

Comment: Yes, if he was naked.

Comment: Is the person *Iron Man?*   Or perhaps *Pepper Stark*, yet undecided on changing her name back to Pepper Potts?

Comment: Closely related: [Word that accentuates the stillness of an object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227611/word-that-accentuates-the-stillness-of-an-object)

Comment: Surely  '***stock still***' - *At rest, motionless; without change of place or attitude*. (OED)

Answer (score 1):

It would not be altogether wrong to describe something as ***stark still***, though it would be idiomatically unusual. The classically, and frequently used form of ***stark*** is found in the idiom ***stark naked***.

However, as the OED confirms, there is a sense of ***stark*** which could be  employed with stillness. Though the more recent OED examples do not offer anything which applies to a motionless human being.

> OED Sense 4a:  Of a physical thing: stiff, rigid in form, not supple
>   or flexible; esp. stiffened through drying, cold, or disuse. Formerly
>   also: †bristly, prickly (obs.).

Older examples go back to pre-11th century.

> 1854   A. E. Baker Gloss. Northamptonshire Words   Stark or Starky,
>   stiff, dry.
>
> 1883   R. Bridges Prometheus 61   O heavenly fire,..O spirit of rage &
>   might, Who canst unchain the links of winter stark.
>
> 1889   E. Peacock Gloss. Words Manley & Corringham, Lincs. (ed. 2) (at
>   cited word),   This smock's a deal oher stark, I can't wear it while
>   [= until] its weshed.
>
> 1975   Lawrence (Kansas) Daily Jrnl.-World 21 Nov. 1/4   They would
>   try to huddle with substitutes under the stiff stark ‘tents’ created
>   from the pulled-off tarps along the sidelines.
>
> 2008   J. Phillips 100 Devotions for Pastors & Church Leaders II. lii.
>   116   The tubular-shaped body wrappings, stark and stiff like a
>   canister, were empty.